# Incorporate jenkins environment variables into groovy template for email notification

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have several environment variables defined for a project on jenkins, amongst which i want to incorporate some onto the email notification sent before and after build success.

But `groovy.text.Template` does not seem to accept these environment variables.

I have also used *"Inject environment variables to the build process    Help for feature: Inject environment variables to the build process"* and defined my variable as follows

```
BUILD_NAME=${BUILD_NAME}
```

where `BUILD_NAME` is accepted as a parameter while i execute the build.

Please could someone help me on this.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the email-ext Jenkins plugin to send out emails, there is a "build" object that contains a lot of information about your Jenkins job.

I would do the following:

1. Print out the properties inside this object by adding the following code to your template:

   `<% println build.properties.collect{it}.join('<br />') %>`
2. View the email template output. You can either use the Jenkins "Email Template Testing" feature or just run your job. You should see a whole bunch of "KEY=VALUE" print outs.
3. Look for the environment variable you are interested in. If your environment variable is listed in `environment={BUILD_NUMBER=45, BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME=#45...}`, you can just call `build.environment['BUILD_NUMBER']` to get 45.
4. If you want to inject custom environment variables I would suggest installing the [Env Inject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin), defining your variables through that plugin and then looking for the variable in build.envVars

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can try this

```
template.make(build.environment)
```

[Source](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2013/07/jenkins-template-plugin-builder.html)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I understood your question, but in order to read that parameter in the template you need to call it like this (if BUILD_NAME is a parameter in the jenkins job:

```
${ENV, var="BUILD_NAME"}
```

This will return the value of that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get it working

```
 <td style="color: #153643; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;padding: 20px 0px;" width="60%">
                             <a  href="<%= build.absoluteUrl %>"> <%= build.envVars['JOB_BASE_NAME'] %>  </a>
                         
                          </td>
```

build.envVars has all the env variables as a dictionary. Use key value pair to access the variables.

Answer (score -1):

Just do:

```
<% def env = build.environment %>
<% def name = env.build_name %>
<% if (name != "") { %>
  Name: <%=name %>
<% } %>
```